# React variable not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a react/firebase course and following the instructor code as below. I looked for any typo errors and not sure why im getting the

`images is not defined` error

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getImages()
    }   

    getImages = async() => {
            let imagesInRTDB = firebase.database().ref('classification/newPhotos').orderByChild('viewed').equalTo(false)

            await imagesInRTDB.on('value',(snapshot) => {
                let images = []
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                    let childKey = childSnapshot.key
                    let childData = childSnapshot.val();

                    childData.rtdbkey = childKey
                    images.push(childData)
                })
            })

            
            if(images.length > 0) {
                this.setState({
                    imagesThatNeedInference: images,
                    nextImage: [images.length - 1],
                    currentImageFb: images[images.length - 1].url
                })
            }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Move `let images = []` outside the `onValue` callback scope. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: ok that worked. but why did the instructor define images within the callback and not get any error?

Comment: They've a typo as well? ‍♂️ Was their code running?

Comment: Or they put the `if(images.length>0)` code block inside the firebase callback.

Comment: Using `await` here doesn't make sense, since [`.on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Query#on) doesn't return a promise, which means that your if-statement will be evaluated before your images array has been populated (you'll need to move if(images.length > 0) into the callback like Tsvetan mentioned)

Comment: I agree with @NickParsons, there's nothing to await for, I think the `if (images.length)` block belongs in the callback.

Comment: yeah later in the video, the instructor got the same error and moved the if block in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare an image variable like this.
Please try this.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getImages()
    }   

    getImages = async() => {
            let imagesInRTDB = firebase.database().ref('classification/newPhotos').orderByChild('viewed').equalTo(false)
            let images = []
            await imagesInRTDB.on('value',(snapshot) => {
                
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                    let childKey = childSnapshot.key
                    let childData = childSnapshot.val();

                    childData.rtdbkey = childKey
                    images.push(childData)
                })
            })

            
            if(images.length > 0) {
                this.setState({
                    imagesThatNeedInference: images,
                    nextImage: [images.length - 1],
                    currentImageFb: images[images.length - 1].url
                })
            }
    }
```

Comment: or you can replace like this `var images = []` in your code

Comment: Please check this URL, it will be helpful.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp